# URL rewrite issue for custom php page outside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a page portfolio.php. I want to show each user portfolio. Link for this page in url I would like to show SEO friendly like /portfolio/user123, /portfolio/userxxx. I am using wordpress latest and permalink set as /%postname.

For the above I edited wordpress .htaccess file and put my rewrite code like following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ portfolio.php?user=$1 [NC]
   </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

portfolio.php page is under root public_html folder and wordpress files and folders also under root public_html.

Currently when I see the URL it looks:
http://www.example.com/portfolio.php?user=abc15

But I want like:
http://www.example.com/portfolio/abc15

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess you are doing the redirect from http://www.example.com/portfolio/abc15 to http://www.example.com/portfolio.php?user=abc15 and not the other way around.

How are the portfolio links generated on your wordpress?
You should generate your wordpress links to www.example.com/portfolio/abc15 and with this .htaccess it will redirect you to the good url.

Comment: I want http://www.example.com/?portfolio.php?user=abc15  to http://www.example.com/portfolio/abc15. Is anything wrong in .htaccess? Please suggest

Comment: I am not generating links for portfolio. Actually portfolio.php page will show portfolio of user to get id from url like $_GET['user'] and will display user portfolio. In that case I want such that will show user portfolio and also url rewrite to http://www.example.com/portfolio/abc15  Here abc15 want to have with $_GET['user'].